# Can I safely copy an existing laravel project and rename it locally for another project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sometimes my internet is slow/off and I don't have the ability to download via composer,so can I safely create a laravel project via the command

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel`

and keep that raw project locally to use for another time, or should I use the composer each time I want to start a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer is **YES**.

actually I do that and I keep a starting project on my local environment with all the vendors ready, npm modules installed and the vueJs ready to use. and every time I start a project all what I need to do is just a copy.